# Click on element which is dynamically generated using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir-webdriver

I have the following HTML code :

```
<table class="report" width="100%">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="alt">
<td>
<a onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;" href="/search/searches/1563/reports/946">56175-746-45619568-noor.fli.zip</a>
</td>
<td class="_"> Report </td>
<td class="_"> 09 Apr 2012</td>
<td class="_"> Noor</td>
<td class="_"> 2.8 MB</td>
<td class="_">Ready</td>
</tr>
```

I want to click on `href="/search/searches/1563/reports/946">56175-746-45619568-noor.fli.zip` but I do not want to use XPATH. I tried a lot of things but failed, is there a way to click on this href without using XPATH. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add an id attribute to the <a> and then click on it by that?

Comment: There are quite a few alternative options to XPath. Can you provide the other options you have tried, so that we do not suggest solutions that you already know will not work?

Comment: It also helps to consider 'what you know' about the page..  will that table always be there, is the format of the link URL predictable and unlikely to change? If there are many tables, is there some text or other element inside this one that tells you it is the 'right' table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the href

```
br.link(:href => '/search/searches/1563/reports/946').click
```

or the text

```
br.link(:text => '56175-746-45619568-noor.fli.zip').click
```

or you can use variations with regex matches

```
br.link(:href => /reports/).click
```

or

```
br.link(:text => /noor.fli.zip/).click
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave `br.link(:href => /reports/).click` worked!

Answer (score 1):

Is it the only link in that table?  or always the first link in that table?

```
browser.table(:class => 'report').a.click
```

If there are multiple tables, then you have to figure out how to find the one you want.  perhaps by the text inside the table.   If in your example the text Noor is unique to that table, then you could try something like this

```
browser.table(:class => 'report', :text => /Noor/).a.click
```

or if you know the structure above will persist where the link and the info about the report are on a single table row)

```
browser.row(:text => /Noor/).a.click
```

You'd have to try to decide which is going to be the most robust or least brittle

Comment: Your code is always so clean that I almost feel ashamed. Neoruby should change their answer vote to yours.

Comment: not necessarily, mine would only work if there is only a single table with that class, and what he wants is always the first link in the table.  That's a lot of assumptions.   If the href pattern is just as predictable, yours works just as well. (and perhaps might not break if someone adds other links to the table to enable more functionality for the user.)

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden so I tried your code, as you pointed out there are multiple tables with that class and the one I want to click is not the first table. The above code worked but was clicking the first table which not what I wanted to click. I think in general the DOM code for this needs to be better with more div ids.

Comment: In that case you need to figure out how to identify the right table.  I generally start out with 'how do I as a human know which table is the right one'  usually that is via some bit of text or a label of some sort inside the table, so you could then try using that to identify which table is the one you want.